# RSA Encryption Padding issues between Python and Java

Tags: java, android, python, cryptography, padding

I am trying to RSA encrypt some data in python using a public key that was generated by a client in android. The encryption goes successfully (atleast there are no exceptions). However, when trying to decrypt the data using the private key in android it throws a bad padding exception.

Relevant Code :

Generating RSA Key Pair in Android. A cutdown version of Bouncy castle is included in android:

```
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;

KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
kpg.initialize(2048);
return kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

Encryption in Python :

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import base64
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

# key contains the public key string without any line breaks. 
def encrypt(keyString, plainText) 
    key = key.replace('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----', '')
    key = key.replace('-----END PUBLIC KEY-----', '');
    pubkey = RSA.importKey(base64.b64decode(key))
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pubkey, hashAlgo=SHA256)
    encrypted = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
    return base64.b64encode(encrypted)

print encrypt('-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA7fJDt9my7WTnPahyw9JvIwm/q3F9jF9R2qNv01Os5NhBUgWOha67DlalOhQmQYBosnXfTWm6JQF2upnBInFGUOZx+10UVnuUbTpUT004lBfNbHx23rrf66b48Q25OoDnbWM3xWD8+9GPvoLO3ftJSbcjb+euzVJOkJYNo33dnG0yZ4LWHLBMog7OgbnjjobiM+O/0wzmiW8VE7gCrg7ZyGpxHXo9ACJytKjC4Hg976Ryg1wyrD2dmgiV212CcBGdzj7F6xn1Uyk7DTeAOgQJHLDFr+2sHgcXJXyslrjvCp3Om2CbzDY9W8XaU2A/84Q1Ejt8ljtJZBOJCuH+ARqZRwIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----', 'this is a test string')
```

Decryption in Android. A cutdown version of Bouncy castle is included in android :

Relevant Imports :

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.OAEPParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PSource;
import java.security.spec.MGF1ParameterSpec;
import java.util.*;
import android.util.Base64;
```

Decryption :

```
private static String RSA_CONFIGURATION = "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding";
private static String RSA_PROVIDER = "BC";

public static decrypt(Key key, String encryptedString){
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_CONFIGURATION, RSA_PROVIDER);
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1,
                    PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT));
    byte[] decodedBytes = c.doFinal(Base64.decode(base64cypherText.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT));
    clearText = new String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8");
}
```

Exception :

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: data hash wrong
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:478)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1204)
    at org.ambientdynamix.security.CryptoUtils.decryptRsa(CryptoUtils.java:204)
```

Test Keys :

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA7fJDt9my7WTnPahyw9JvIwm/q3F9jF9R2qNv01Os5NhBUgWOha67DlalOhQmQYBosnXfTWm6JQF2upnBInFGUOZx+10UVnuUbTpUT004lBfNbHx23rrf66b48Q25OoDnbWM3xWD8+9GPvoLO3ftJSbcjb+euzVJOkJYNo33dnG0yZ4LWHLBMog7OgbnjjobiM+O/0wzmiW8VE7gCrg7ZyGpxHXo9ACJytKjC4Hg976Ryg1wyrD2dmgiV212CcBGdzj7F6xn1Uyk7DTeAOgQJHLDFr+2sHgcXJXyslrjvCp3Om2CbzDY9W8XaU2A/84Q1Ejt8ljtJZBOJCuH+ARqZRwIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Please post the private key, post functions and imports and the version of the bouncy castle library used.

Comment: Updated Question. Forgot to mention that this was on Android.

Comment: Posted a working solution for this problem here : http://shivamverma.info/2015/06/09/compatible-rsa-encryption/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OAEP padding has two parameters:

- message digest algorithm
- mask generation function

I see in Java you use SHA-256 and MGF1 with SHA-1 hash. They must be not matching to parameters used by Python.

Difference between Python and Java is that Python code uses the same digest for message digesting and mask digesting. While Java (Sun provider and BouncyCastle provider) use SHA-1 for mask digesting by default. So one need to specify all parameters explicitly:

```
byte[] cipherTextBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(cipherText);
byte[] privateKeyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(privateKeyStr);

KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec ks = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(ks);

Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey, new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256",
        "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT));
byte[] plainTextBytes = c.doFinal(cipherTextBytes);
String plainText = new String(plainTextBytes);

System.out.println(plainText);
```

Comment: When creating the encryption cipher in python, I specify SHA256 as the hashAlgo and if I dont specify the mask function, it defaults to MGF1. Mentioned in the docs here : https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/2.6/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_OAEP.PKCS1OAEP_Cipher-class.html

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked hash. From source it seems it also uses MGF1 as mask generation function. Then it just should work. The reason it doesn't could be data gets corrupted somewhere. Sample data is required to say anything definite.

Comment: Added some sample data. In case it helps.

Comment: @ShivamVerma Without the private key that's unlikely. You should also try and post a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've added all the code and it shouldn't be too difficult generating a key pair and cipher text.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to deal with this problem:

By default `mgfunc` is consistent with `hashAlgo`

so,we can change the `mgfunc` like that:

```
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(pubkey, hashAlgo=SHA256,mgfunc=lambda x,y:MGF1(x,y,SHA1))
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue I had to append new line character at end of each line in my private key string

```
  private RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKey(String filename) throws Exception {
    String privateKeyPEM        =   getKey(filename);
    privateKeyPEM               =   privateKeyPEM.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
    privateKeyPEM               =   privateKeyPEM.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    byte[] encoded              =   Base64.decodeBase64(privateKeyPEM);
    KeyFactory kf               =   KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec =   new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
    RSAPrivateKey privKey       =   (RSAPrivateKey) kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    return privKey;
}


private String getKey (String filename) throws IOException {
    String responseContent  =   null;
    try (InputStream stream =   this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + filename); 
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"); 
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(streamReader)) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append (line + "\n");
        }
        responseContent = builder.toString();
    }
    catch (IOException expGeneral) {
        logger.error("Cannot load Crypto related file [" + filename + "].", expGeneral);
        throw expGeneral;
    }
    return responseContent;
}
```

Above is the solution